# Tensorflow AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'deprecated'

Tags: python, tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network, lstm

I'm new to tensorflow and I'm testing the tutorial example of [LSTM](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/tutorials/recurrent/index.html).
I download the code and dataset following the instructions, and run the following command to run the program:

```
wget http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~imikolov/rnnlm/simple-examples.tgz
tar xvf simple-examples.tgz
python ptb_word_lm.py --data_path=simple-examples/data/
```

But the program is not executable and reports the following error message:

```
File "ptb_word_lm.py", line 332, in main tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary("Training Loss", m.cost)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'deprecated'
```

What did I do wrong? Here is the version information of my system:

```
Pip version: pip 1.5.4
Python version: 2.7.6
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Tensorflow version: tensorflow-0.12.0rc0-cp27-none-linux_x86_64
```

Thank you all for your kind help!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to replace all

```
tf.contrib.deprecated.scalar_summary()
```

with

```
tf.scalar_summary()
```

in ptb_word_lm.py

Details are described [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/train.html#scalar_summary).